# CSS: Width de 100% real

Tags: css, css3

Buen día. Tengo un body de ancho del 100% y dentro un div del mismo ancho. El problema es que el div está tomando 100% de la pagina *visible* y no el 100% real.

Es decir, si tengo la ventana del explorador de internet cambiada de tamaño, y me aparecen las flechas de movimiento horizontal, el 100% del div se convierte en el ancho total de la página **que estoy viendo en el momento**, pero no cubre la parte a la que accedo con las flechas de desplazamiento hacia la derecha.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 950px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.header {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-image:url(img/bg.jpg); margin:0; padding:0; width:100% ">
  <div class=header style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); height:125px; ">
    <div class=wrapper style="width:950px; margin: auto; height:125 ">
      <img style=" width:200px;  float:left; position:absolute; top:20px;" src=img/dsd.png>
      <div id=boton style="position:absolute;  top:40; left:785">
        <a href="service.html"> <img src=img/service.png width=170/> </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Por favor, añade el código que llevas hasta ahora

Comment: Fernando, te recomendaría que te dieses una vuelta por el tour de SO, y aprendas a formular correctamente las preguntas. Antes de que tu pregunta sea cerrada, intenta actualizarla y poner **en tu pregunta** el código y **no en una respuesta**.

Comment: La que estás liando Fernando!!!

Comment: Ya lo he editado por tí, Facundo. Te invito a [hacer el tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com) y a consultar nuestra guía [*Cómo preguntar*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ¿Por qué eliminaste mi edición? Vaya hombre, relájate. Solo haz click en el ícono `</>` en el editor y pega tu código allí. Luego guarda cambios y está.

Comment: Lo siento, estoy intentando copiar el código entero por mi mismo (porque faltaba un trozo) y no lo logro u.u

Comment: A ver. En el editor verás un ícono de un archivo con `</>`. Ese ícono te desplegará una modal en donde solo tienes que pegar tu código HTML y CSS. Luego, solo guardamos cambios y eso es todo :)

Comment: es que sí veo el codigo pegado en el editor, pero no en la publicación

Comment: Fernando pega el código de cualquier manera y ya lo editamos nosotros tranquilo

Comment: ahora sí, jajaja, gracias

Comment: Voy a editar tu publicación. Por favor, **ya no edites**.

Comment: Ya está editada. Ya no tienes que editar Facundo.

Comment: gracias, lo siento :D

Comment: Fernando, estás utilizando **inline-styles** estilos CSS desde la misma línea del elemento, esto es una mala práctica, además tienes un monton de fallos en el código. Crea en el head de tu página el `<style>` y desde ahí utiliza los selectores CSS. Aquí te dejo una guía rápida https://www.w3schools.com/css/

Comment: Además de lo que te comenta mi estimado amigo @Javi, lo que ocurre es que el contenido se *"desborda"*, haciendo que aparezclan las scrollbars. Por ende, si especificas que tendrá un ancho del `100%`, todo lo que exceda será tomado como un desborde (`overflow`) y solo será visible mediante scrollbars. En lugar de `width` puedes usar `min-width: 100%;`.

Comment: Dejando a parte los fallos del código o sus posibles soluciones, te recomiendo que empieces por lo más sencillo aunque sea dar color a un **background de un `<div>`** y después puedes ir añadiendo más aspectos a ese mismo elemento e ir entendiendo que hace cada uno. Suerte Fernando!

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos.

Comment: @FacundoDíaz de nada!

Comment: @FacundoDíaz por favor no abandones tus preguntas. Marca la respuesta que consideres correcta.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que ocurre se llama *desbordamiento* y ocurre cuando un elemento hijo excede las dimensiones de su padre. Esto es normal en elementos con ancho fijo, como son los elementos `block` o cualquier elemento con un ancho definido. Si no quieres que ocurra un *desborde* en el padre, entonces hazlo `inline-block` o si estás usando flexbox, `inline-flex`:

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.parent,
.parent2 {
  background-color: tomato;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 50%;
}

.parent2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}

.child {
  background-color: gold;
  height: 50px;
  width: 80vw;
}

h3 {
  color: #444;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<h3>Con ancho fijo</h3>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<h3>Con ancho relativo</h3>
<div class="parent2">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Como siempre dando buenas respuestas :) 

Answer (score 0):

Debes siempre tener en cuenta el padre y sus características, estas dando un valor de `width: 100%` al padre y el siempre tomara el 100% del ancho de la pantalla pero fíjate que dentro tiene un hijo con clase `wrapper` que tiene establecido un tanto en `px` y esto al ajustar otros anchos de pantalla, siempre empujara y te generara un `scroll` horizontal cuando la pantalla tenga un ancho menos a `950px`.

```
.wrapper {
  **width: 950px;**
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Una posible solucion es que si queires que tenga el tanto `%` del contenedor del padre, se lo asignes en porcentaje.

Ahora bien, si buscas otras soluciones puedes hacer un `width: calc();` o ajustarlo mediante `@media`

Answer (score 0):

prueba asi:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 950px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.header {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

Debería hacer lo que imagino que necesitas ;)

El último margin-bottom: 0px; lo puedes omitir tambien ya que esta dentro del margin: 0px; de unas lineas arriba.

Un saludo.